# Can I add same value for range partition in PostgreSQL-12?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_prop_demand_dtls_mango 
PARTITION OF tbl_prop_demand_dtls_partition
FOR VALUES FROM (28) TO (28);
```

I got this error

```
ERROR:  empty range bound specified for partition "tbl_prop_demand_dtls_mango"
DETAIL:  Specified lower bound ('28') is greater than or equal to upper bound ('28').
```

Answer (score 2):

Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

> When creating a range partition, the lower bound specified with FROM is an inclusive bound, whereas the upper bound specified with TO is an exclusive bound.

The declaration

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_prop_demand_dtls_mango 
PARTITION OF tbl_prop_demand_dtls_partition
FOR VALUES FROM (28) TO (29);
```

defines a range for values greater or equal to 28 and less than 29. If the column is integer then the range contains only 28.